# Excel - if one of three values is true then set true

Tags: excel

i do not manage it to make a simple =(IF(OR(...)) formula to get "TRUE" if one of the cells in different columns contains "TRUE"

i`ve tried it with if and or

[IF OR formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIptO.png)

Comment: Just use `OR`, there's no need for `IF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this works for me:

Assume A1, B1 and C1 contain False, False and True respectively, then

```
=or(A1,B1,C1)
```

in cell D1 will return true.

Then you can expand with if() as so:

```
=if(or(A1,B1,C1),"Yes","No")
```

To have Yes or no instead of true and false - True & false are recognized by excel as 1 and 0.